# How can one deploy a PowerShell api to Azure Functions thru VSC?

Tags: powershell, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

How can one deploy a Powershell api to Azure Functions. The [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/tutorials/functions-extension/create-function) only talks about deploying a JavaScript function.

One doesn't get an option to select 'Powershell' during language selection while creating a 'Project' thru the Azure Functions extension.

This is a default Powershell api when deployed from the Azure Portal.

```
# POST method: $req
$requestBody = Get-Content $req -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$name = $requestBody.name
# GET method: each querystring parameter is its own variable
if ($req_query_name) 
  {$name = $req_query_name}
Out-File -Encoding Ascii -FilePath $res -inputObject "Hello $name"
```

I tried to deploy the below code directly using the VSC Azure Function's 'Deploy' button. But I get the below error.

```
Unable to write Workspace settings because no workspace is opened. Please open a workspace first and try again
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unable to write Workspace settings because no workspace is opened. Please open a workspace first and try again.

In VSCode, we have to open a folder or create a function project first, or the file to hold Workspace settings can't be created, and we will get the error when trying to modify Workspace settings like runtime, language and template filter.

Detailed Steps of Developing Azure Function in VSCode(references from [official tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/tutorials/functions-extension/getting-started)):

**Tips**

1. [Languages like Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#languages) are experimental so don't use them in production. [Powershell](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-powershell-worker#overview)/[Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker#overview) support on 2.x runtime are also in progress.
2. [Install functions core tools(cli)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools#versions) to debug functions locally.

   1.x for OS Windows .NET Framework, 2.x for cross platform .NET Core.

**Install Azure Function Extension**

Input `vscode:extension/ms-azuretools.vscode-azurefunctions` in brower, it will open VScode and install extensions.

**Create a Function project**

1. Create an empty folder in File explorer ; say `MyFunctionApp`
2. Log into Azure Account.
3. In Azure Function Extension, Click `Create New Project` and point to created folder `MyFunctionApp`.
4. Select language JavaScript

**Create a Function**

1. Click `Create Function` and browser `MyFunctionApp` folder. Then you may see the dropdown menu as below. Project runtime is automatically set based on cli installed.

   [image]
2. Click `Change template filter` and change it to `All` so that we can see all templates available.
3. Click `Change project language` to select experiment language like `Powershell`.
4. Follow the rest prompt to create an Http trigger.

**Debug or run function locally**

For c#, javascript and java, feel free to `F5.`

To run function in experimental language locally, open terminal in VSCode(Ctrl+`) and run `func host start`, no debug support so don't use `F5`.

To test a httptrigger, suffix function url with `?name=World!` to get Hello World response from your URL.

**Deploy**

Click `Deploy to Function App` button and follow the prompt.

Comment: The official "Getting Started" has Node.js package manager as a prerequisite. But one shouldn't need node.js to deploy a PowerShell API, no?

Comment: @AyanMullick Yes, this Node.js and npm requirement is used to install Azure function core tools to run functions locally. If you only want to deploy and test online, no need to install node related resources.

Comment: Working on it. Stuck on Pre-requisites. Can't get $func to work.

Comment: @AyanMullick You are trying to run function cli locally, it requires installing nodejs and npm on Windows. And `$` is an shell signal on OS like Mac, just run `func` if you have installed function core tools.

Comment: @AyanMullick Have updated my answer with details, see whether it's useful for you.

Comment: Steps taken
1. Create Function
2. Select a blank folder
3. It prompts for project initialization. I say Yes.
4. Select `JavaScript` for language selection
5. `Change project runtime` and `~1(Approved for Production use)` [Screen](https://imgur.com/a/zOoiVEu)
6. And it gives an error `Unable to write Workspace settings because no workspace is opened. Please open a workspace first and try again` [Screen](https://imgur.com/a/RTwCeYr)

Comment: @AyanMullick Got it. You should open a folder first in VSCode or create a function project first, or the file to hold `Workspace settings` can't be created, and you will get the error when trying to modify runtime.

Comment: Thanks.Followed exact steps.It deploys successfully as per VSC. [log screen](https://imgur.com/a/cf2IHVU). However, there is no actual function in the functions app. [Screen](https://imgur.com/8F1Ty0l). However, the root URL is accessible. [Screen](https://imgur.com/a/pAmSOHb)

Comment: @AyanMullick Make sure after clicking `Deploy to Function App`, you choose the whole function app folder instead of the function folder. Go to `https://<functionappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/`, you should see a host.json with a folder named after your function. In this folder, there are function.json, run.ps1, etc.

Comment: @AyanMullick thanks for your edit, I reorganize my words with your detailed steps .