# OpenAPI specification configuration for Azure Functions PowerShell API

Tags: azure, azure-functions, swagger-2.0, azure-api-management

How can one configure, thru Visual Studio Code, a PowerShell API running in Azure Functions so that it can be consumed as an OpenAPI-Specification API from Azure API management like [this URL](http://conferenceapi.azurewebsites.net?format=json), as mentioned in the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-and-publish)?

Currently, if I try to add the below PowerShell API as an OpenAPI-Specification API in Azure API management it gives an error

```
Unable to parse specified file. Please ensure it is valid OpenAPI specification document.
```

Azure functions PowerShell API URL: 
 https://vscpsapi.azurewebsites.net/api/VSCPSapi

Comment: @Jerry Liu, Can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**

Things have changed, when we click API definition in V2 Function app, see

> Function API definition (Swagger) feature is not supported for V2 runtime currently.

And We can [import Function app to API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-function-app-as-api#add-new-api-from-azure-function-app) directly without API definition.

---

You need to create an OpenAPI definition for your Azure Function first.

See [Create OpenAPI Definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-openapi-definition#generate-the-openapi-definition).

Steps:

1. Platform features > API definition.
2. Under API definition source, choose `Function(Preview)` to consume your HTTP trigger as the API handler.
3. Generate API definition template > Save.
4. Paste the following swagger template for a httptrigger function template.

Then modify it with your function app and trigger name. Remove `security` part if your function authorization level is anonymous.

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: <myfunctionapp>.azurewebsites.net
  version: 1.0.0
host: <myfunctionapp>.azurewebsites.net
basePath: /
schemes:
  - https
  - http
paths:
  /api/<MyHttpTrigger>:
    get:
      operationId: /api/<MyHttpTrigger>/get
      description: Send a name to API to get Hello name back
      summary: Get Hello name
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: name
          description: Name to send
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Return Hello name
      security:
        - apikeyQuery: []
    post:
      operationId: /api/<MyHttpTrigger>/post
      description: Send a name to API to get Hello name back
      summary: Get Hello name
      consumes:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: requestbody
          in: body
          description: Name to send
          required: true
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              name:
                type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Return Hello name
      security:
        - apikeyQuery: []
securityDefinitions:
  apikeyQuery:
    type: apiKey
    name: code
    in: query
```

5. When you add API in API management, you can choose `OpenAPI specification` or `Function App`.

   If you leave security part as your function authorization level is Admin/Function, you have to find function key in `Manage` blade of function dropdown menu and update the Backend URL in `Inbound Processing`.

   [image]

   You may get an explicit prompt for adding the key when you choose `Function App`.

   > Function App "funcappname" has been imported. Please make sure to replace the values of the following Named Values with the secrets of your functions: funcappname_triggername_query_xxxxxx.
6. See [OpenAPI 2.0 docs](https://app.swaggerhub.com/help/tutorials/writing-swagger-definitions) if you need modification on your swagger.

Comment: One thing to note that this is going to be changed soon. Function import to APIM will not require API definition to be present.

Comment: I'm doing just the Get operation now. Isn't there a way to specify this while deploying thru VSC? I'm getting an error `Make sure the server at VSCPSapi.azurewebsites.net accepts GET requests from functions.azure.com` [Screen](https://imgur.com/kJQoIv2). However, it's working on APIM thru OpenAPI Spec

Comment: @AyanMullick About setting thru VSC, see my update. As for the tip, it's Not an error, only to remind you this test code running on azure portal is cross origin and requires CORS settings on your function. By default, `function.azure.com` is in your CORS list. If you have any web app which will call this api using js in browser, just add their sites to the CORS. See it in Platform features, under API definition.

Answer (score 0):

APIM supports import of:

- OpenAPI spec
- WSDL
- WADL

Content at your link - https://vscpsapi.azurewebsites.net/api/VSCPSapi - is neither of those. I'm not sure about it's format at all. So it cannot be imported.

Comment: It was deployed as per the steps discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51547380/how-can-one-deploy-a-powershell-api-to-azure-functions-thru-vsc/51604565?noredirect=1#comment90397282_51604565).